# Override recently viewed widget in magento 2

Tags: magento2, recently-viewed

I have added a recently viewed widget in home page 
[image]

I want to remove add to cart button in the recently viewed widget.

Comment: How did you add the widget?

Comment: with overidding template file you can change display.

Comment: @AnshuMishra widget added via admin side->addwidget

Comment: @PareshaU vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\web\template\product\addtocart-button.html    extended to ->app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\web\template\product\addtocart-button.html and vendor\magento\modulecatalog\view\base\web\template\product\list\listing.html  extended to ->app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\web\template\product\list\listing.html

Comment: @PareshaU I tried to remove add to cart button from above mentioned path but its not work

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai  can you please help to figure out this problem?

Comment: Can you tell which template you are using for recently viewed products?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i use grid template

Comment: @Nismathvi Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the below file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml

Your file location will be like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]]/Magento_Reports/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml

Below is the php code which you will find top of the above file:

```
<?php
if ($exist = ($block->getRecentlyViewedProducts() && $block->getRecentlyViewedProducts()->getSize())) {
    $type = 'widget-viewed';
    $mode = 'grid';

    $type = $type . '-' . $mode;

    $image = 'recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget';
    $title = __('Recently Viewed');
    $items = $block->getRecentlyViewedProducts();

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $rating = 'short';
    $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
}
?>
```

You need to set **$showCart = false** to hide **"Add to cart"** button. And you can manage the contents according to your requirement.

Don't forget to flush the cache.

Comment: is there any additional folder that i need to copied to the theme?

Comment: No need to copy anything. Only the above mentioned file.

Comment: button is still there

Comment: Are you working with the correct template?

Comment: yeah i have working with Magento_catalog/templates/product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml

Comment: Please follow the above. You are on wrong path as your mentioned grid contains only few lines of code which doesn't contains the above code.

Comment: sorry that is my bad i tried with Magento-reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml but still not work add to cart button is still showing

Comment: It should work as I have already checked and its working fine for me.

Comment: it's not wokring, 
I have added file app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]]/Magento_Reports/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml
but it's not overriding

Comment: Need to modify layout?